Cronet POST reesponse blocked: POST response UrlCallback onResponseStarted not getting called till UploadDataSink.onReadSucceded(true)
I am using Cronet POST request to transfer large file of unknown size , but if the server sends any negative response the response is not being passed to urlcallback.onresponseStarted till entire content uploaded and call uploadDatasink.onreadsucceded(true). Basically post request response is not coming to cancel the upload. Example code of mine looks like below
import org.chromium.net.CronetEngine;
import org.chromium.net.UploadDataProviders;
import org.chromium.net.UrlRequest;
import org.chromium.net.UrlResponseInfo;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class CronetPostExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CronetEngine.Builder myBuilder = new CronetEngine.Builder(context);
        CronetEngine cronetEngine = myBuilder.build();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
ExecutorService dataexecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        UrlRequest.Callback callback = new UrlRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onRedirectReceived(UrlRequest request, UrlResponseInfo info, String newLocationUrl) {
                request.followRedirect();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponseStarted(UrlRequest request, UrlResponseInfo info) {
                request.read(ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024));
            }

            @Override
            public void onReadCompleted(UrlRequest request, UrlResponseInfo info, ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
                byteBuffer.clear();
                request.read(byteBuffer);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSucceeded(UrlRequest request, UrlResponseInfo info) {
                System.out.println("Request succeeded with response: " + info.getHttpStatusCode());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed(UrlRequest request, UrlResponseInfo info, CronetException error) {
                System.err.println("Request failed: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        };

        UrlRequest.Builder builder = cronetEngine.newUrlRequestBuilder(
                "https://example.com/post-endpoint",
                callback,`your text`
                executor
        );

        byte[] uploadData = "This is the POST data".getBytes();
        builder.setHttpMethod("POST")
                .setUploadDataProvider(new MyUploadDataProvider(), dataexecutor )
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

        UrlRequest request = builder.build();
        request.start();
    }
}




public class MyUploadDataProvider extends UploadDataProvider {

    

    public MyUploadDataProvider() {
        
    }

    @Override
    public long getLength() {
        return -1; //for chunked upload of unknown length
    }

    @Override
    public void read(UploadDataSink uploadDataSink, ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
       if(finalchunk) uploadDataSink.onReadSucceded(true) 
       else uplodaDataSink.onReadSucceded(false)
    }

    @Override
    public void rewind(UploadDataSink uploadDataSink) {
      
    }
}

I used different executors to avoid any thread blocakges issue.
